# Filling aggregated column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

Using the input below as an example, I am trying to create an aggregated column in a dataframe in Python based on unique instances of others. The best attempt I can make leaves some NaN in the new column though

```
raw_data = {'RegionCode' : ['10001', '10001', '10001', '10001', '10001', '10001', '10002', '10002', '10002', '10002', '10002', '10002'],
            'Stratum' : ['1', '1','2','2','3', '3', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
            'LaStratum' : ['1021', '1021', '1022', '1022', '1023', '1023', '2021', '2021', '2022', '2022', '2023', '2023'],
            'StratumPop' : [125, 125, 50, 50, 100, 100, 250, 250, 200, 200, 300, 300],
            'Q_response' : [2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]}



Data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['RegionCode', 'Stratum', 'LaStratum', 'StratumPop', 'Q_response'])

#Sum StratumPop by unique instance of LaStratum at RegionCode level
Data['Total_Pop'] = Data.drop_duplicates(['LaStratum']).groupby('RegionCode')['StratumPop'].transform('sum')

Data
```

What I am trying to do is sum the StratumPop column at RegionCode level by each unique instance of LaStratum. The totals produced are correct but how can I 'fill' the column to repeat each total instead of just seeing the first occurence of each different total and NaN for the others? So Region 10001 has 275 on every row and Region 10002 has 750 on each row. Is this possible without creating staging tables and merging unique values back in (as I'm currently doing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill the column and repeat each Total_Pop per Region, you can use a simple grouped (by Region per se) `ffill()`:

```
Data['Total_Pop_new'] = Data.groupby('RegionCode')['Total_Pop'].ffill()
```

Will give you back:

```
Data

   RegionCode Stratum LaStratum  ...  Q_response  Total_Pop  Total_Pop_new
0       10001       1      1021  ...           2      275.0          275.0
1       10001       1      1021  ...           1        NaN          275.0
2       10001       2      1022  ...           4      275.0          275.0
3       10001       2      1022  ...           1        NaN          275.0
4       10001       3      1023  ...           2      275.0          275.0
5       10001       3      1023  ...           2        NaN          275.0
6       10002       1      2021  ...           3      750.0          750.0
7       10002       1      2021  ...           4        NaN          750.0
8       10002       2      2022  ...           3      750.0          750.0
9       10002       2      2022  ...           2        NaN          750.0
10      10002       3      2023  ...           1      750.0          750.0
11      10002       3      2023  ...           4        NaN          750.0
```

Answer (score 1):

well see

```
Total_pop=Data.drop_duplicates(['LaStratum']).groupby('RegionCode')['StratumPop'].sum()
```

Now create a function:-

```
def func(val):
    if val==Total_pop.index[0]:
        return Total_pop.values[0]
    else:
        return Total_pop.values[1]
```

Finally make use of `apply()` method

```
Data['Total_pop']=Data['RegionCode'].apply(func)
```

Output:-

```
    RegionCode  Stratum     LaStratum   StratumPop  Q_response  Total_pop
0   10001   1       1021    125     2   275
1   10001   1       1021    125     1   275
2   10001   2       1022    50      4   275
3   10001   2       1022    50      1   275
4   10001   3       1023    100     2   275
5   10001   3       1023    100     2   275
6   10002   1       2021    250     3   750
7   10002   1       2021    250     4   750
8   10002   2       2022    200     3   750
9   10002   2       2022    200     2   750
10  10002   3       2023    300     1   750
11  10002   3       2023    300     4   750
```